# How is the detach method used to make code "less expensive"?

Tags: jquery, performance

While looking up the `.detach()` jQuery method on the [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/) site, under the "Removing Elements" section, I came across the passage below:

> The .detach() method is extremely valuable if you are doing heavy
>   manipulation on an element. In that case, it's beneficial to .detach()
>   the element from the page, work on it in your code, then restore it to
>   the page when you're done. This limits expensive "DOM touches" while
>   maintaining the element's data and events.

What would be an example of the "heavy manipulation" on an element and how would detaching an element from a page make the code more efficient? Please show an example of when this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the reflow of browser.. when you add/remove elements or do certain css changes in the dom tree it triggers a reflow in the browser... so if you do a lot of changes inside a particular element it might trigger multiple redraws... but if you detach the element then it will trigger one redraw, the changes made in the detached object will not trigger a redraw because it is not part of the dom tree.... then again when you reattach the element it will trigger another reflow.... thus you will finish the operation with just 2 reflows instead of multiple ones

[Rendering: repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)

Comment: So the ideal situation using detach() would be to detach an element form the DOM, apply any other jQuery methods to it and then re-insert it to the DOM when all necessary changes have been made?